# Error using jsr166.jar library: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I have written a program that uses the ForkJoinPool class, this class being found in the rt.jar library in JDK 7 and the jsr166.jar library for JDK 6.

I am compiling the program in netbeans on a computer that has JDK 7 but wish the program to be usable on computers that only have JDK 6.

The Source/Binary Format used when compiling with netbeans is JDK 6. I originally compiled the program with the library rt.jar (from JDK 7) however when I ran the program originally on the JDK 6 computer I saw the error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.util.concurrent
```

Following the instructions which appear on this website https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/java-forkjoin-parallel-programming.html#comment-86433.

I downloaded jsr166.jar and, having put jsr166.jar into correct directory and the Run-time libraries, attempted to use the command line:

```
java -Xbootclasspath/p:lib/jsr166.jar -jar code.jar $@
```

However this produces the error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger : Unsupported major.minor version 53.0
```

The version 53.0 alluded to, according to wikipedia is JDK version 9.

AtomicInteger is called from within teh ForkJoinPool.java class.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
```

Could anyone offer me advice on how to run this?

Thank you very much

Comment: You probably have multiple versions of Java on the system. Try compiling from the command line where you'll be sure of the version.

Comment: I do have multiple versions. I have jdk1.7.0_51 on my computer and also some .jar libraries in a directory to be used by the netbeans project. I am using both of these libraries however. I am using classes from jdk1.7.0_51 however all these classes seem to be okay when compiled in JDK 6 format on netbeans except these java/util/concurrent/ files. So I am trying to find a way to keep accessing the classes from jdk1.7.0_51 and also still use these new classes while compiling in the JDK 6 format. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the file **jsr166.jar** - also known as **Concurrency JSR-166** - that you are using was compiled with JDK 9. The ForkJoinPool is part of this API, and as you want to use it with JDK 6, you need to download a version of this API compiled for JDK 6.

The creator of this API is Dough Lea, and you will find the correct version to download from his page: http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/concurrency-interest/

Repeat the procedure that you have done, now using the **new jsr166.jar** compiled for JDK 6, and remove the **old jsr166.jar** from your project.